# Find a substring with minimum distance

Tags: c++, strings

Problem statement for finding given substring:

> Given a random string S and another string T with unique elements,
>   find the minimum consecutive sub-string of S such that it contains all
>   the elements in T.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> S='adobecodebanc'
> T='abc'
> answer='banc'
> ```

How could I have improved the code from construction of code? Should I have created one more compare function? Did I use too many variables? Could I have optimized the code further and much more?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int a, int b, int c);
int max(int a, int b, int c);

int main(void)
{
    char string1[] = "adobecodebanc";
    char *pstring = string1;
    int first_char = -1;
    int second_char = -1; 
    int third_char = -1;
    int final_distance = 1000;
    int final_min = 0;
    int final_max = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    /* iteratre over the string and compare each characeter*/
    while (*pstring != '\0')
    {
        /* if any character matches substring condition
           assign index value of the string to that variable  */
        if (*pstring == 'a' || *pstring == 'b' || *pstring == 'c')
        {
            if (*pstring == 'a')
            {
                first_char = counter;
            }
            else if (*pstring == 'b')
            {
                second_char = counter;
            }
            else
            {
                third_char = counter;
            }

            if (first_char != -1 && second_char != -1 && third_char != -1)
            {
                /* get the min and max index value difference*/
                int min_1 = min(first_char, second_char, third_char);
                int max_1 = max(first_char, second_char, third_char);
                int distance = max_1 - min_1;

                /*track the minimum substring so far*/
                if (distance < final_distance)
                {
                    final_distance = distance;
                    final_min = min_1;
                    final_max = max_1;
                }
            }
        }
        pstring++;
        counter++;
    }

    int temp = final_min;

    while (final_max >= temp)
    {
        std::cout << string1[temp];
        temp++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

/* Find the min index value*/
int min(int first_char, int second_char, int third_char)
{
    if (first_char < second_char)
    {
        if (first_char < third_char)
        {
            return first_char;
        }
        else
        {
            return third_char;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (second_char < third_char)
        {
            return second_char;
        }
        else
        {
            return third_char;
        }
    }
}

/* Find the max index value*/
int max(int first_char, int second_char, int third_char)
{
    if (first_char > second_char)
    {
        if (first_char > third_char)
        {
            return first_char;
        }
        else
        {
            return third_char;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (second_char > third_char)
        {
            return second_char;
        }
        else
        {
            return third_char;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are already the functions `std::min` and `std::max` that you should use. It either takes 2 elements or an `std::initializer_list`, so you could use

  ```
  int min_1 = std::min({first_char, second_char, third_char});
  ```

  There is also `std::minmax` to get both the minimum and the maximum, possibly more efficiently than calling `std::min` and then `std::max`. Not that it matters for your application, but it is a good habit to get into.

  There is also `std::none_of` to check if none of `first_char`, `second_char` and `third_char` are `-1`, but the use is awkward because it needs a predicate.
- Use range based for when possible. In this case you iterate over all the chars in the string, so it is easy:

  ```
  //while (*pstring != '\0')
  //for (const char c : string1)
  for (const char c : "adobecodebanc")
  ```
- If you initialize `first_char`, `second_char` and `third_char` with `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` you could leave out the check if all of them are not -1. You need to be careful for when printing though.
- I assume this is supposed to be a general function for any string. If that string is "erf" the function prints "e". That doesn't seem right.
- `main(void)` is considered bad style in C++. In C a function `void f();` takes any number of arguments, so `f(234, 2)` compiles fine. To make that fail to compile you have to write `void f(void)`. In C++ `f(234, 2)` doesn't compile and `void f(void)` is redundant, making you look like a C programmer trying out C++.
- `final_distance` is initiated to "some big number". It makes sense to use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` instead of `1000`.
- Use `const` when it makes sense, for example for `min_1`, `max_1` and `distance`.
- Putting it all together it looks like this:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <algorithm>

  int main()
  {
      char string1[] = "adobecodebanc";
      int first_char = -1;
      int second_char = -1;
      int third_char = -1;
      int final_distance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
      int final_min = 0;
      int final_max = 0;
      int counter = -1;

      /* iteratre over the string and compare each characeter*/
      for (const char c : string1)
      {
          counter++;
          /* if any character matches substring condition
             assign index value of the string to that variable  */
          if (c == 'a')
          {
              first_char = counter;
          }
          else if (c == 'b')
          {
              second_char = counter;
          }
          else if (c == 'c')
          {
              third_char = counter;
          }
          else{
              continue;
          }

          if (first_char != -1 && second_char != -1 && third_char != -1)
          {
              /* get the min and max index value difference*/
              const auto minmax = std::minmax({first_char, second_char, third_char});
              const int distance = minmax.second - minmax.first;

              /*track the minimum substring so far*/
              if (distance < final_distance)
              {
                  final_distance = distance;
                  final_min = minmax.first;
                  final_max = minmax.second;
              }
          }
      }

      int temp = final_min;

      while (final_max >= temp)
      {
          std::cout << string1[temp];
          temp++;
      }
      std::cout << std::endl; //should not be needed since the program exits
      return 0; //gets implicitly added if you leave it out
  }
  ```

  I feel like I'm missing an obvious improvement, so I'll take a look again later.

Comment: Be aware that that for-range-loop also iterates over the terminator!

Comment: Since you are using C++, please consider using `std::string` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: @mrm - thanks for reminder - hard to get over C habits :)